# Tips on evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(x^2)}}{1-\cos x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Maybe you have any tips on evaluating this limit?

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(x^2)}}{1-\cos x}$$

Comment: is this $$1-\cos(x)^2$$ under the square root?

Comment: Have you learned about Taylor series yet?

Comment: Not yet actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}$$ for $\theta$ near $0$.  Therefore,$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x^2}}{1-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt 2\sin(x^2/2)}{1-\cos x}
$$
and now you can use l'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{\sin^2x}\cdot\dfrac{1+\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cos( x^2)}}$$ as $\sin(x^2)>0$ for $x\to0$

Comment: Maybe you could give more explanation to what you have done here?

Comment: @Tomtomas i think he multiplied both term by $(1+\cos x)\sqrt{1+\cos (x^2)}$, also from there you can reduce it and transform terms so it came to $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip:

$$ \cos( \theta ) = \cos( 2 \frac{\theta}{2} ) =  \cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) - \sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) $$

$$ 1= \cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) + \sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) $$

$$ 1 - \cos( \theta ) = 2 \sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) $$

Ced